# Subgroups of $GL(2, \Bbb{R})$

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

I am wondering if a subgroup of $GL(2,\Bbb{R})$ which is constructed by  all rotations and all matrices in the form of 
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{l l}
a & x \\
0 & \sqrt{a}
\end{array}
\right] \ \ \ (a \in \Bbb{R}^+, x \in \Bbb{R})
$$
would be a proper subgroup of   $GL(2,\Bbb{R})^+:=\{a \in GL(2, \Bbb{R}):\ \det(a)>0\}$ or it gives us the whole group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinants of all your matrices in your subgroup would be positive, so it can't be all of $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$. If you quotient by the subgroup I'm not sure whether you get $\{-1,1\}$, or whether there is more stuff missing from your subgroup.

Comment: That was a typo, I meant a proper subgroup of $GL(2,\Bbb{R})^+=\{a \in GL(2, \Bbb{R}):\ \det(a)>0\}$.